# Symfony 6.2, Form without entity: How to translate Constraint messages?

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I have this Form:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form;

use App\Security\Validator\Constraints\PhoneValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class JobApplicationType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email',options:[
                'label'=>'form.label.email',
                'constraints'=> [
                    new Email(message: 'form.error.email')
                ]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'translation_domain'=>'job-application'
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this translations:

```
form:
  label:
    email: 'E-Mail'
  error:
    email: 'Invalid E-Mail'
```

The label forms.label.email will be translated correctly. When I change the label to
forms.error.email, it is also translated correctly.
But the constraint message is not being translated, no matter if I provide
new Email(message: 'form.error.email')
or
new Email(['message'=>'form.error.email'])

I am using Symfony 6.2.7

What am I doing wrong?

Update: Using the Translatorinterface:

```
$this->translator->trans('form.label.email',domain: 'job-application')
```

works, but this seems a little to complicated for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use translation keys in constraint validation message, but you need to put your translation in validators.en.yaml because the domain must be validators. I think you just put in messages.en.yaml.

And by the way, Symfony validator messages are not extracted automatically.

I hope it will help you!